# Трансляция веб камеры в PyQt5

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5, opencv, qlabel

Хотел добавить видеопоток с камеры и отображать его в определнном виджете, но не получалось. 
Использовал виджет `QVideoWidget(name QVideo1)` (его плохо видно, но он выделен пунктиром справа).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Основной код для камеры я использовал вот такой

```
def can():
    # камера
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # camera ID or insert FULL video file path
    while True:
        ret, image = cap.read()
        cv2.imshow('Video', image)
        if cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
            #конец камеры
```

Полный код программы с дизайном представлен ниже:

```
rom PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtMultimediaWidgets, QtMultimedia
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
import cv2

class Ui_Widget(object):
    def setupUi(self, Widget):
        Widget.setObjectName("Widget")
        Widget.resize(943, 465)
        self.image_folder = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Widget)
        self.image_folder.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 240, 111, 41))
        self.image_folder.setObjectName("image_folder")
        self.open_word = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Widget)
        self.open_word.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 240, 111, 51))
        self.open_word.setObjectName("open_word")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Widget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 290, 111, 51))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.simulation = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Widget)
        self.simulation.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 440, 80, 21))
        self.simulation.setObjectName("simulation")
        self.QVideo1 = QVideoWidget(Widget)
        self.QVideo1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 20, 311, 201))
        self.QVideo1.setObjectName("QVideo1")


        self.retranslateUi(Widget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Widget)

    def retranslateUi(self, Widget):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Widget.setWindowTitle(_translate("Widget", "Widget"))
        self.image_folder.setText(_translate("Widget", "Открыть фотки"))
        self.open_word.setText(_translate("Widget", "Открыть ворд"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Widget", "Удалить фотки"))
        self.simulation.setText(_translate("Widget", "симуляция"))

def can():
    # камера
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # camera ID or insert FULL video file path
    while True:

        ret, image = cap.read()
        cv2.imshow('Video', image)

        if cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
            #конец камеры

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Widget()
    ui.setupUi(Widget)
    Widget.show()

    ui.simulation.clicked.connect(can)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Требуется отобразить видео с камеры в этот виджет. Я пробывал разные варианты, также находил на *stack overflow* вариант, но мне он не помог. Пока остаётся только этот,но он открывает видео в новом окне.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets 
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_Widget(object):
    def setupUi(self, Widget):
        Widget.setObjectName("Widget")
        Widget.resize(943, 465)
        
        self.image_folder = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Widget)
        self.image_folder.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 240, 111, 41))
        self.image_folder.setObjectName("image_folder")
        self.open_word = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Widget)
        self.open_word.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 240, 111, 51))
        self.open_word.setObjectName("open_word")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Widget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 290, 111, 51))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        
        self.simulation = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Widget)
        self.simulation.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 440, 80, 21))
        self.simulation.setObjectName("simulation")
        
        '''
        self.QVideo1 = QVideoWidget(Widget)
        self.QVideo1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 20, 311, 201))
        self.QVideo1.setObjectName("QVideo1")
        '''
# +++ -----> vvvvvvvvvvv   vvvvvv
        self.label_video = QLabel(Widget)
        self.label_video.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 20, 311, 201))
        self.label_video.setObjectName("label_video") 

        self.retranslateUi(Widget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Widget)

    def retranslateUi(self, Widget):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Widget.setWindowTitle(_translate("Widget", "Widget"))
        self.image_folder.setText(_translate("Widget", "Открыть фотки"))
        self.open_word.setText(_translate("Widget", "Открыть ворд"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Widget", "Удалить фотки"))
        self.simulation.setText(_translate("Widget", "симуляция"))


# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class ThreadOpenCV(QThread):
    changePixmap = pyqtSignal(QImage)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)         
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 24)

        while True:
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if ret:
                frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                frame_expanded = np.expand_dims(frame_rgb, axis=0)           
                rgbImage = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                h, w, ch = rgbImage.shape
                bytesPerLine = ch * w
                convertToQtFormat = QImage(
                    rgbImage.data, w, h, bytesPerLine, QImage.Format_RGB888)
                p = convertToQtFormat.scaled(311, 201, Qt.KeepAspectRatio) 
                self.changePixmap.emit(p)

                if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
                    break
                    
            self.msleep(20)      
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
           

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Widget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)            

        self.simulation.clicked.connect(self.can)
# +++        
        self.thread = ThreadOpenCV()                                      # +++    
        self.thread.changePixmap.connect(self.setImage)                   # +++


    def can(self):
        self.thread.start()                                               # +++

    def setImage(self, image):                                            # +++
        self.label_video.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))              # +++        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: От души родной,спасибо))

Comment: @Erasurs пожалуйста. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: извини,не сможешь ли ты мне пояснить, как сделать вывод изображения с камеры без кнопки,сразу при запуске программы?

Comment: @Erasurs попробуйте после строки `self.thread.changePixmap.connect(self.setImage)`  добавить строку `self.simulation.click()`  . Если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос.