# Трансляция видеопотока с камеры

Tags: python, pyqt5, opencv, qt-designer

Есть кнопка и виджет `qlabel` для передачи изображения с камеры (выделен пунктиром).

Нужно при запуске программы передавать изображение с камеры в виджет `qlabel`, 
а при нажатии кнопки выводить в полноэкранное отображение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня пока получилось только выводить изображение на полный экран при нажатии кнопки отдельным окном, код представлен ниже.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import cv2
class Ui_Widget(object):
    def setupUi(self, Widget):
        Widget.setObjectName("Widget")
        Widget.setEnabled(True)
        Widget.resize(500, 500)
        self.video = QLabel(Widget)
        self.video.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 431, 201))
        self.video.setObjectName("video")
        self.pushButton1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Widget)
        self.pushButton1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 250, 91, 31))
        self.pushButton1.setObjectName("pushButton1")

        self.retranslateUi(Widget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Widget)

    def retranslateUi(self, Widget):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Widget.setWindowTitle(_translate("Widget", "Widget"))
        self.pushButton1.setText(_translate("Widget", "push"))

def can():
        
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  
        while True:
            ret, im = cap.read()
            cv2.namedWindow('Res', cv2.WINDOW_KEEPRATIO)
            cv2.imshow("Res", im)
            cv2.resizeWindow("Res", 1920, 1080)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('f'):
                break
        cv2.destroyWindow("Res")

       

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Widget()
    ui.setupUi(Widget)
    Widget.show()
    ui.pushButton1.clicked.connect(can)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что нужно, чтобы при запуске программы видео с камеры было в маленьком окошке, а при нажатии на кнопку - выводилось на полный экран?

Comment: @S.H.
Именно так

Answer (score 0):

Я не совсем понял зачем вам кнопка, а также рекомендую познакомиться с классами:

Класс [**QCamera**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcamera.html) предоставляет интерфейс для системных камер.

Класс [**QCameraViewfinder**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcameraviewfinder.html) предоставляет виджет viewfinder камеры.

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__ ()
        
        self.cameraView = QCameraViewfinder()
        self.cameraView.setMinimumSize(320, 240)
        self.cameraInfo = QCameraInfo.defaultCamera()
        
        self.camera = QCamera(self.cameraInfo)
        self.camera.setViewfinder(self.cameraView)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self) 
        self.layout.addWidget(self.cameraView)

        if self.camera.status() != QCamera.UnavailableStatus:
            self.camera.start()
       
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.resize(400, 300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

---

**Update**

> просто требуется показывать в маленьком окне и при этом, чтобы была возможность выводить на полный экран, при этом выходить из полного экрана и продолжалось показываться в маленьком. Не знаю понятно ли озвучил
>
> я представил только часть программы и именно тут нужно, чтобы при запуске программы выводить изображение в маленьком виджете, а при нажатии на кнопку новое окно на полный экран.

Ну если вам так надо, тогда нажимайте на кнопку и смотрите.

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

from q1408004 import CameraView                                        # +++ # !!!


class Ui_Widget(object):
    def setupUi(self, Widget):
        Widget.setObjectName("Widget")
        Widget.setEnabled(True)
        Widget.resize(500, 500)

# +++ -------------> vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv                                # !!!
        self.video = CameraView(Widget)                                # - QLabel(Widget)
        self.video.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 431, 201))
        self.video.setObjectName("video")
        self.video.setStyleSheet('background-color: #D98C00;')
        
        self.pushButton1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Widget)
        self.pushButton1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 250, 91, 31))
        self.pushButton1.setObjectName("pushButton1")

        self.retranslateUi(Widget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Widget)

    def retranslateUi(self, Widget):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Widget.setWindowTitle(_translate("Widget", "Widget"))
        self.pushButton1.setText(_translate("Widget", "push"))


# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class Window(QWidget, Ui_Widget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__ ()
        
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton1.setCheckable(True)                            # +++
        self.pushButton1.clicked.connect(self.can)

    def can(self, status):
        if status:
            self.showFullScreen()                                      # !!!
            w = self.width()
            h = self.height()
            self.video.setMaximumSize(w, h)
            self.video.setMinimumSize(w, h)
        else:
            self.video.setMinimumSize(431, 201)
            self.video.setMaximumSize(431, 201) 
            self.showNormal()                                          # !!!
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            
       
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**q1408004.py**

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class CameraView(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        self.cameraView = QCameraViewfinder()
        self.cameraInfo = QCameraInfo.defaultCamera()
        
        self.camera = QCamera(self.cameraInfo)
        self.camera.setViewfinder(self.cameraView)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self) 
        self.layout.addWidget(self.cameraView)

        if self.camera.status() != QCamera.UnavailableStatus:
            self.camera.start()
       
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = CameraView()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: просто требуется показывать в маленьком окне и при этом,чтобы была возможность выводить на полный экран, при этом выходить из полного экрана и продолжалось показываться в маленьком.Не знаю понятно ли озвучил

Comment: @Zatass все что вы написали в комментариях делает мой пример. Еще раз - что не так в моем примере.

Comment: я представил только часть программы, и именно тут нужно,чтобы при запуске программы выводить изображение в маленьком виджете, а  при нажатии на кнопку новое окно на полный экран

Comment: @Zatass я обновил свой ответ, проверьте.

Comment: запускается,но не выдает изображение,я думаю нужно где-то указать cv2.VideoCapture(0), я попробую разобраться,но заранее спасибо вам,вы всё равно очень помогли.

Comment: @Zatass что вы запускаете? Вам просто надо скопировать два модуля `main.py` и `q1408004.py` , и запустить `python main.py` и все. Я не использовал в своем примере  `cv2`.

Comment: да,я так и делаю, но видео с встроенной камеры не отображается,не в маленьком окне,не на большом экране. Видимо он не отображает мою встроенную камеру.

Comment: Есть ли возможность использовать cv2?

Comment: @Zatass все возможно. Какое видео у вас не отображается?  Работает ли у вас мой первый пример?

Comment: нет,он как и второй пример не отображает картинку(видеопоток с камеры)
я нашёл ваш пример с другого ответа,приблизительно похожий на то что надо мне,немного по-другому,возможно я смогу в нём разобраться и пойму как можно сделать дополнительно кнопку  на расширение окна на полный экран (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1406705/%d0%a2%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b2-pyqt5/1406720#1406720)

Comment: Если у вас есть возможность подсказать,как это можно сделать,я был бы вам очень признателен,потому что при использовании библиотеки cv2 у меня отображается видопоток с камеры.

Answer (score 0):

> Я нашёл ваш пример с другого ответа [**Трансляция веб камеры в PyQt5**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1406705/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B2-pyqt5/1406720#1406720), приблизительно похожий на то что надо мне, немного по-другому, возможно я смогу в нём разобраться и пойму как можно сделать дополнительно кнопку на расширение окна на полный экран.
>
> Если у вас есть возможность подсказать, как это можно сделать, я был бы вам очень признателен, потому что при использовании библиотеки **`cv2`** у меня отображается видеопоток с камеры.

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_Widget(object):
    def setupUi(self, Widget):
        Widget.setObjectName("Widget")
        Widget.setEnabled(True)
        Widget.resize(500, 500)

        self.video = QWidget(Widget)
        self.video.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 431, 201))
        
        self.label_video = QLabel(Widget, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)        
        self.label_video.setObjectName("label_video")

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.video) 
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label_video)
        
        self.pushButton1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Widget)
        self.pushButton1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 250, 91, 31))
        self.pushButton1.setObjectName("pushButton1")

        self.retranslateUi(Widget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Widget)

    def retranslateUi(self, Widget):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Widget.setWindowTitle(_translate("Widget", "Widget"))
        self.pushButton1.setText(_translate("Widget", "push"))


# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class ThreadOpenCV(QThread):
    changePixmap = pyqtSignal(QImage)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.w = 311
        self.h = 201

    def run(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)         
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 24)

        while True:
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if ret:
                frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                frame_expanded = np.expand_dims(frame_rgb, axis=0)           
                rgbImage = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                h, w, ch = rgbImage.shape
                bytesPerLine = ch * w
                convertToQtFormat = QImage(
                    rgbImage.data, w, h, bytesPerLine, QImage.Format_RGB888)
                p = convertToQtFormat.scaled(self.w, self.h, Qt.KeepAspectRatio) 
                self.changePixmap.emit(p)

                if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
                    break
                    
            self.msleep(20)      
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 

class Window(QWidget, Ui_Widget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__ ()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton1.setCheckable(True)       
        self.pushButton1.clicked.connect(self.can)
        
# +++        
        self.thread = ThreadOpenCV()                                      # +++    
        self.thread.changePixmap.connect(self.setImage)                   # +++
        
        self.pushButton1.click()

    def can(self, status):
        self.thread.start() 
      
        if not status:
            self.showFullScreen()                                         # !!!
            w = self.width()
            h = self.height()
            self.video.setMaximumSize(w, h)
            self.video.setMinimumSize(w, h)
            
            self.thread.w = w
            self.thread.h = h
        else:
            self.video.setMinimumSize(431, 201)
            self.video.setMaximumSize(431, 201) 
            self.showNormal()                                             # !!!
            
            self.thread.w = 431
            self.thread.h = 201

    def setImage(self, image):                                            # +++
        self.label_video.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))              # +++   
        
       
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]